# define keys in multidimensional array from csv

Tags: php, csv

I want to compare two arrays, one coming from a shoppingcart and the other one parsed from a csv-file. The array from the shopping cart looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 07.39
            [name] => walkthebridge
            [subtotal] => 7.39
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 07.39
            [name] => milkyway
            [subtotal] => 7.39
        )
)
```

The array from my csv-file however looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => walkthebridge
            [2] => 07.39
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => milkyway
            [2] => 07.39
        )
```

)

and is build using this code

```
$checkitems = array();
    $file = fopen('checkitems.csv', 'r');

          while (($result = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {

          $checkitems[] = $result;
          }

    fclose($file);
```

how can i get the keys in the second array to match those in the first one? ( So that 0 would be id, and 1 would be name and so on)

thanks in advance

Comment: There's ambiguity in your example if column 0 in your CSV relates to the quantity field or the ID.

Comment: mhm, in the csv there is no field for quantity, it's only the id wich shows up in both arrays. As i have mapped the keys properly now (namely "id") this should be no problem anymore, or am i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
while (($result = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
    $checkitems[] = array(
        'id' => $result[0],
        'name' => $result[1],
        'price' => $result[2]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say $oldArray is your second 'csv' array, then:

```
$newArray=array();
foreach($oldArray as $v){
  $t=array();
  $t['id']=$v[0];
  $t['name']=$v[1];
  // etc...
  $newArray[]=$t;
}
```

Not tested, but that's one way of mapping the key values..

Answer (score 0):

csv isn't an associative key value storage method. if you want to do that you will need to do it by your self.

at any event you can use [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)